# Remove part of the string in json document using str replace for many records

Tags: regex, r, string-matching, stringr

I would like to replace a string in this file which is causing the invalid json arguments. I can manually delete the first string "_id" : ObjectId( "539163d7bd350003" ), and can convert this json to a data frame. Is there a way I can replace all the instances of json file with function like str_replace. I tried the following but couldn't make it work. Any suggestions?

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(stringr)

json_file<- '{ "_id" : ObjectId( "539163d7bd350003" ), "login" :    "vui", "id" : 369607, "avatar_url" : "https://avatars.mashupsusercontent.com/u/369607?", "gravatar_id" : "df8897ffebe16c5b0cd690925c63e190", "url" : "https://api.mashups.com/users/vui", "html_url" : "https://mashups.com/vui", "followers_url" : "https://api.mashups.com/users/vui/followers", "following_url" : "https://api.mashups.com/users/vui/following{/other_user}", "gists_url" : "https://api.mashups.com/users/vui/gists{/gist_id}", "starred_url" : "https://api.mashups.com/users/vui/starred{/owner}{/repo}", "subscriptions_url" : "https://api.mashups.com/users/vui/subscriptions", "organizations_url" : "https://api.mashups.com/users/vui/orgs", "repos_url" : "https://api.mashups.com/users/vui/repos", "events_url" : "https://api.mashups.com/users/vui/events{/privacy}", "received_events_url" : "https://api.mashups.com/users/vui/received_events", "type" : "User", "site_admin" : false, "org" : "amurath" }'

str_replace(json_file,"_id*" , "")
json_file <- fromJSON(json_file)


json_file <- lapply(json_file, function(x) {
x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
unlist(x)
 })

df<- do.call("rbind", json_file)
df<- data.frame(json_file)
```

Comment: @akrun no need of `str_replace_all`.. since `id` is there once per doc (mongodb)

Comment: @karthikmanchala  It was just a guess as the OP's code worked with the example given

Comment: The problem was with the string itself. I can replace the word like "login" with the function you mentioned but I want to replace this type of string ""_id" : ObjectId( "539163d7bd350003" ), " with ""and I have the numbers in object id which keep changing with records!

Comment: yes it is working great! I need to check for multiple records!

Comment: @karthikmanchala I am getting this errror! Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\"_id[^,]*,\s"

Comment: @user3570187 use `str_replace(json_file,"\"_id[^,]*,\\s*" , "")` observe `\\s*`

Comment: I have multiple instances of id and i used replace all. Noticed that the when i load it as a json file it displays the data like this. { \"_id\" : ObjectId( \"539321adbd35430c6b000002\" ), \"login\" : \"phieffs\". I wonder what is causing the issue to replace all

Comment: @karthikmanchala I posted a follow up question. Can you answer the question? I used the following code as you can see in other thread. str_replace_all(json,"union[^}]*}\s*, ""). I think you are the best person who can answer this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
str_replace(json_file,"\"_id[^,]*,\\s*" , "")
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vA6mZ3/7)

Comment: I am trying to do [link] (https://regex101.com/r/vA6mZ3/15) for another problem. I cannot directly use it in R str_replace. Can you suggest str_replace_all(json_file, "\",{author[^*]*],\\s*","")?