# Parsing Exported JSONs from mongoDB In R

Tags: r, json, mongodb

I'm trying to read an exported JSON file from mongoDB into R studio. I try:

```
library(jsonlite)
test <- fromJSON
```

And I get the error:

```
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                   {       "_id" : ObjectId("5c36dff4eb0ba56804da8
                 (right here) ------^
```

I assume it's because the JSON looks like:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5bec6b265a394b484832c767"),
```

where the ObjectID() throws off the JSON parser.

Something similar occurs throughout the rest of the JSON where the value is prefixed by, say, ISODate(string) or NumberInt(integer). So, my question is: how do I read these documents in without encountering the lexical error and yet still maintain whatever properties the prefixed term imparts?

I've tried looking through mongoDB documentation, but if there's an answer there I haven't found it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789823/remove-part-of-the-string-in-json-document-using-str-replace-for-many-records

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632708/r-json-file-to-dataframe-using-tidyjson

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713038/error-in-parsing-a-json-file-in-r

Comment: Maybe look into using a package like `RMongo` https://www.kenwalger.com/blog/nosql/mongodb/using-r-mongodb/ rather than parsing the json

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the RMongo package. Exporting as strict, assuming I did it right, didn't work and gives this error when using fromJSON():

`Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       admin.artists.strict.json
                     (right here) ------^`

Where the ^ points at admin.